# Shifting graph in TikZ: centre not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am having trouble making a diagram align in `tikzpicture`. At the moment if I use '\centering', my network graph moves to the right of the pdf. If I don't, it is in the left of the pdf. How do I make it centre?
Thanks

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,sgame,color,fullpage,tikz,caption,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
\newtheorem{assumpt}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{e.g.}{Example}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
          \begin{tabular} {lp{3cm}} &
\begin{tikzpicture} [shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                    thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}, ]

  \node[main node] (1) {$m_{12}$};
  \node[main node] (2) [left of=1] {$w_{11}$};
  \node[main node] (3) [ below of=1] {$m_{22}$};
  \node[main node] (4) [right of=1] {$w_{12}$};
    \node[main node] (5) [right of=4]   {$m_{13}$};
  \node[main node] (6) [below of=5] {$m_{23}$};
  \node[main node] (7) [ below of=6] {$m_{33}$};
  \node[main node] (8) [right of=5] {$w_{13}$};



\draw
 (1) --  (4)
 (3) --  (4)
 (5) --  (8)
 (6) --  (8)
 (7) --  (8);




\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Initial $\bar{g}$}
\label{tikz}
\end{tabular}



\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Try removing the `tabular` environment. Do you need it here?

Answer (score 3):

You won't need the `tabular` environment. Remove these two lines:

```
\begin{tabular} {lp{3cm}} &
.
.
.
\end{tabular}
```

from your code. Also, since you are putting your `tikz` picture inside `figure*` environment (why not use `figure` instead), you won't need to use `\captionof` but `caption`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,sgame,color,fullpage,tikz,caption,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
%          \begin{tabular} {lp{3cm}} &
\begin{tikzpicture} [shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                    thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}, ]

  \node[main node] (1) {$m_{12}$};
  \node[main node] (2) [left of=1] {$w_{11}$};
  \node[main node] (3) [ below of=1] {$m_{22}$};
  \node[main node] (4) [right of=1] {$w_{12}$};
    \node[main node] (5) [right of=4]   {$m_{13}$};
  \node[main node] (6) [below of=5] {$m_{23}$};
  \node[main node] (7) [ below of=6] {$m_{33}$};
  \node[main node] (8) [right of=5] {$w_{13}$};



\draw
 (1) --  (4)
 (3) --  (4)
 (5) --  (8)
 (6) --  (8)
 (7) --  (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Initial $\bar{g}$}
\label{tikz}
%\end{tabular}



\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Alexandra Also please use `\caption` instead of `\captionof{figure}` and don't use `figure*` unless you're in a `twocolumn` mode.